# Base64 Encoded to Decoded File Conversion Problem

Tags: java

I am processing very large files (> 2Gig). Each input file is Base64 encoded, andI am outputting to new files after decoding. Depending on the buffer size (LARGE_BUF) and for a given input file, my input to output conversion either works fine, is missing one or more bytes, or throws an exception at the outputStream.write line (IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough bits). Here is the code snippet (could not cut and paste so my not be perfect):

```
.
.

final int LARGE_BUF = 1024;
byte[] inBuf = new byte[LARGE_BUF];

try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inFile); OutputStream outStream new new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {

   for(int len; (len = inputStream.read(inBuf)) > 0); ) {
      String out = new String(inBuf, 0, len);
      outStream.write(Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(out.getBytes()));
   }
}
```

For instance, for my sample input file, if LARGE_BUF is 1024, output file is 4 bytes too small, if 2*1024, I get the exception mentioned above, if 7*1024, it works correctly. Grateful for any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "64 bit encoded"? I suspect (given your code) that you mean "base-64 encoded" which is rather different.

Comment: May you clarify what is exactly the problem you're trying to solve here? You say it works sometimes but you also say when `LARGE_BUF` is `7*2012`, it works correctly.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I am sorry, you are correct, I meant base64 encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are converting bytes into a String, then immediately back into bytes.  So, remove the use of String entirely.

Second, base64 encoding turns each sequence of three bytes into four bytes, so when decoding, you need four bytes to properly decode three bytes of original data.  It is not safe to create a new decoder for each arbitrarily read sequence of bytes, which may or may not have a length which is an exact multiple of four.

Finally, Base64.Decoder has a [wrap(InputStream) method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#wrap%28java.io.InputStream%29) which makes this considerably easier:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = Base64.getDecoder().wrap(
    new BufferedInputStream(
        Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(inFile))))) {

    Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get(outFile));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @VGR. I have performed some limited testing on this today. I need to see how it handles more representative file sizes after the weekend. Thanks for the insights and understanding about the nuances of the byte conversion implications for coding efforts.

Comment: Thanks again @VGR. Ok, I have finished my testing. This works fine. I am grateful. There seems to be a ceiling, performance-wise, that this runs up against. A file that is, say, 5Gig in size, is taking 5-7 minutes to process. I understand that there is a "chunk size" I might be able to tweak to improve the performance that I have not looked into. However, you solved my issue so thats the main thing.